# Visual Studio Web Deployment - update publish profile to "Precompile during publishing"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, microsoft-web-deploy

I currently have a website that is run on Windows Server 2012 R2. I have deployed my site to a specific folder on the server without using the "precompile during publishing" option. The website works and runs fine.

However, in order to improve the performance of my site, I want to update my publish profile to precompile during publishing. Will I need to delete the existing website files on the server? And what is the best way/practices of going about with this change in order not to break anything?

Note: The website is still new, so I do not need to preserve any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating thepublish profile works fine and the publishing takes care of the rest. It removes what needs to be removed, precompiles the code and thereafter publishes it to the server.

[image]

Using the above settings maintains the website state without causing any issues. So no other action is required from you in terms of handling the server.